# Conditional Comment ie7 not working

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements, stylesheet

So I put the ie7 conditional comment in my head tag directly underneath the comment to pull up the original style.css file:

Then  I made a css file called ie7.css made a few changes in the css...

Checked IE7 to look at the site http://www.sgconstruction.org and no changes were visible...

I have no idea why it's not making any changes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: the css link of ie7 not working ? I mean this http://www.sgconstruction.org/wordpress/wp-content/themes/SG/ie7.css

Comment: Thanks bro!  You totally gave me the right hint to get it working!!!  I had the incorrect link because I'm using wordpress I needed to make a php call to the file!  Thanks for the help I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple calls to stylesheet links. After your IE7 conditional, the main style sheet (themes/SG/style.css) is called again, making your conditional stylesheet pointless (at it's current location).

Comment: Ooooohhhh!!!!  I truly appreciate your quick response!  Thanks for the tip man... I will be looking through the code... learning more things everyday!  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to badger a bit more about this topic, but just for clarification... if i remove all the main stylesheet call ups (apart from the first one)... then I should see my ie7.css work in action?

Comment: Glad to help. If this solves the issue, you should mark the question answered by clicking the check mark next to the answer. To answer the comment question.... Yes. The Conditional call to IE should be the LAST stylesheet call in the header.

Comment: THANK YOU SCOTT!!! PROBLEM SOLVED!  THANKS DUDE... I had a REALLY tough time finding the solution to this... you have no idea how thankful I am!  It is answered for sure!

Answer (score 0):

For people who come late, I think this is a better, more up to date way to go about targeting specific versions of IE: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/